# Prevent Defaults prevents whole document from been clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

On my web site i listen for clicks on a href and swap my html using ajax using the code below

```
$(document).on('click','a', function (e){
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({})
.........
})
```

but the prevent default prevents me from clicking any other thing on the page until the ajax complete.
I am listening to the click on  tags while referencing the document as root because if the ajax swaps the content, using just  and listening to events on that won't be called because of the changes done by swapping the dom.
What can be done to fix this behavior. Thanks

Comment: Not reproducible. Is there anything else between `e.preventDefault` and the AJAX call? How have you attached listeners to the other elements?

Comment: Nothing else just the ajax

Answer (score -1):

You should try with `id` or `class` intend of `element : a`   that can prevent it I think.